# Algoritmo mais eficiente para encontrar índices dos 2 elementos de uma lista cuja soma é igual a determinado valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, algoritmo

O Desafio é simples, encontrar dois números de uma determina lista que se somados resultam um número específico e retornar o índice desse números.

Isso eu resolvi, o problema é que além disso a performance do código também conta.

> Performance test with a large list of numbers: Time limit exceeded

O que eu tentei que não foi rápido o suficiente, usando dois laços `for` em que o primeiro pegava um número como base e o segundo percorria todos os números que estavam à frente dele, que não foi rápido o suficiente.

Então eu pensei em usar o método `index` com a diferença entre a soma requisitada e o número atual, mas também não é rápido o suficiente. Se alguém souber de algum método mais rápido ou o que eu tenho que pesquisar sobre pra entender.

```
   def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
        result = ()
        for i in range(len(numbers) - 1):
            diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
            try:
                j = numbers.index(diff)
                return (i, j)
            except ValueError:
                continue
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10))
```

Comment: talvez retornando valor diretamente com return (i,j) ao invés de setar pra um variável pra depois dar return

Comment: @FourZeroFive Isso não muda praticamente nada, a diferença é irrelevante, pois o que interfere no algoritmo são outros fatores (como chamar `index` toda hora, por exemplo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que `index` sempre percorre a lista desde o início para buscar pelo índice do elemento, e você faz essa busca várias vezes (e como em muitos casos a diferença não está na lista, ele acaba percorrendo até o final e lançando a exceção, que ainda deve adicionar um *overhead* a mais).

Em vez de verificar se a diferença está na lista, uma alternativa é guardar os números que já visitei em um [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set) (que é uma estrutura que não permite elementos repetidos e é otimizada para buscas - [veja aqui](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) que a busca em `set`'s tem tempo constante, já em listas tem tempo linear).

```
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
    visitados = set()
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
        if diff in visitados:
            return numbers.index(diff), i
        visitados.add(numbers[i])
```

Por exemplo, para a lista `[3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9]` e a soma `10`, primeiro eu vejo o `3` e a diferença para 10 (que é 7). Vejo se o 3 está no `set`, e como não está, adiciono-o lá. Quando eu chegar no `7`, verei que a diferença é 3, que estará no `set`, e portanto sei que 3 e 7 são o par que somados dão 10. Aí basta retornar os índices.

A diferença para o seu código é que eu chamo `index` somente se encontrar os elementos que somados sejam iguais a `target_sum`, o que é melhor que procurar para todos.

Outra opção é usar um dicionário para guardar o índice dos elementos:

```
def find_two_sum_dict(numbers, target_sum):
    visitados = set()
    indices = {}
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
        if diff in visitados:
            return indices[diff], i
        visitados.add(numbers[i])
        if numbers[i] not in indices:
            indices[numbers[i]] = i
```

Isso evita chamar `index` ao final, ao custo de manter outra estrutura adicional (o dicionário de índices).

---

Fiz alguns testes com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
def find_two_sum_index(numbers, target_sum):    
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
        try:
            j = numbers.index(diff)
            return (i, j)
        except ValueError:
            continue

def find_two_sum_set(numbers, target_sum):
    visitados = set()
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
        if diff in visitados:
            return numbers.index(diff), i
        visitados.add(numbers[i])

def find_two_sum_dict(numbers, target_sum):
    visitados = set()
    indices = {}
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        diff = target_sum - numbers[i]
        if diff in visitados:
            return indices[diff], i
        visitados.add(numbers[i])
        if numbers[i] not in indices:
            indices[numbers[i]] = i

from timeit import timeit
from random import sample, shuffle

# executa 100 vezes cada função
params = { 'number': 100, 'globals': globals() }

i = s = d = 0 # computa quantas vezes cada um foi pior
for _ in range(10):
    # gera um array com mil números
    numbers = list(sample(range(10000), 1000))
    # escolhe 2 aleatoriamente e soma
    soma = sum(sample(numbers, 2))
    # embaralha o array
    shuffle(numbers)
    t_i = timeit('find_two_sum_index(numbers, soma)', **params)
    t_s = timeit('find_two_sum_set(numbers, soma)', **params)
    t_d = timeit('find_two_sum_dict(numbers, soma)', **params)
    if t_i > t_s and t_i > t_d: # index demorou mais
        i += 1
    elif t_s > t_i and t_s > t_d: # set demorou mais
        s += 1
    elif t_d > t_s and t_d > t_i: # dicionário demorou mais
        d += 1
print(i, s, d)
```

Como a lista de números que gerei é aleatória, os resultados variam. Mas em geral, na maioria das vezes a solução com `set` (a primeira opção desta resposta) foi mais rápida. Em alguns casos a solução com o dicionário de índices foi mais lenta, mas na maioria das vezes a sua solução foi a mais lenta (foi removida a variável `result` do seu código, que não estava sendo utilizada, pois no fim isso nem interferia muito no resultado, o que deixava mais lento eram as chamadas a `index` mesmo).

Se quiser você pode imprimir os valores de `t_i`, `t_s` e `t_d` (eles indicam quantos segundos demorou cada teste), para ter uma ideia (lembrando que os tempos podem variar muito de uma máquina e/ou execução para outra, pois dependem de vários fatores, como o hardware, se havia outros processos rodando na máquina, etc). Mas em geral, na minha máquina, se comparados com a solução que usa o `set`, a sua solução foi entre 3 e 15 vezes mais lenta (dependendo da lista gerada), e a solução com o dicionário de índices foi entre 1 e 3 vezes mais lenta.

Como você parece estar submetendo o código para um desses "desafios online" e eles não costumam divulgar todos os casos de teste, não tenho como dar certeza que essas soluções passarão. Mas pelo menos parece que já houve alguma melhoria em relação ao seu código.

---

Obs: também testei com o código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/479550/112052) e ele é tão ou mais lento quanto o seu código, já que ele faz uma busca na lista, que como já mencionado, tem tempo linear e por isso é mais lento que usar `set`.

Answer (score -4):

Você deve colocar a lista em ordem, o que permite fazer uma busca binária que tem melhor desempenho que a busca linear. Então você percorre a lista, pegando uma parcela por vez. Com esta parcela você pode calcular a diferença, que é o valor da próxima parcela, e então através da busca binária verifica se ela se encontra na lista.

```
def find_two_sum(numbers, target_sum):
numbers.sort()
for parcela in numbers:
    diferença = target_sum - parcela
    if diferença in numbers:
        return (parcela, diferença)
return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(find_two_sum([3, 1, 5, 7, 5, 9], 10))
```

Comment: Você menciona busca binária mas em nenhum momento a utiliza (o operador `in` [faz uma busca linear](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#line-25))